# What does “$\forall$” mean?

Tags: elementary-functions

I am studying cryptography and in the first lesson I saw "$\forall$" element in the following formula:

> $\forall x\neq x_0:P(X) = 0$

- What does $\forall$ mean?

Comment: For all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's one of the two "quantifiers" used in math and is read as "for all". Even the latex symbol for it, $\forall$, is obtained by writing `$\forall$`.

The other quantifier, $\exists$ (`$\exists$`), is read as "there exists".

The statement $$\forall x\neq x_0:P(x)=0$$ can be translated into English as:

> For all $x$ which are not equal to $x_0$, the expression $P(x)$ is equal to $0$.

[Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic))